# How to remove or overwrite bezierpath at touched point in iphone?

Tags: iphone, uiimage, uitouch, uicolor, uibezierpath

I am using following code to color the image using `UIBezierPath`. There is color picker from which user can select color. And with that color bezier path will be drawn over image. But when user fills color at some position in image.after that it selects color from color picker and again fills the color at same position. In this case previously drawn color is there. I want to remove that previously filled color and want to fill new color. This is only if user fills the color at same position. Here I am already getting the points where `UIBezierPath` is already drawn. There is one method of `UIBezierPath removeAllPoints`. But it's removing all points from path. I only want to remove only touched point from uibezierpath. How can I achieve this?

```
#import "MyLineDrawingView.h"


@implementation MyLineDrawingView
@synthesize selImage;
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) 
    {

        arrBezierPaths=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init ];
        globalPath=[[UIBezierPath alloc]init];

        myPath=[[UIBezierPath alloc]init];

        self.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;

        myPath.lineWidth=30;
        brushPattern=[UIColor redColor];
        NSLog(@"initWithFrame method called");
        NSDictionary *dict=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:myPath,@"Path",brushPattern,@"Color", nil];
        [arrBezierPaths addObject:dict];

    }
    return self;
}


- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{

    for (int i=0; i<[arrBezierPaths count]; i++)
    {
        NSDictionary *dict=[arrBezierPaths objectAtIndex:i];
        UIColor *tempBrushpatter=[[UIColor alloc]init ];
        tempBrushpatter=[dict valueForKey:@"Color"];

        globalPath=[dict valueForKey:@"Path"];

        [globalPath strokeWithBlendMode:kCGBlendModeOverlay alpha:1.0];
      [tempBrushpatter setStroke];

    }

   }

#pragma mark - Touch Methods
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    UITouch *mytouch=[[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];

    [globalPath moveToPoint:[mytouch locationInView:self]];

}
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

UITouch *mytouch=[[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
       CGPoint pointTouched = [mytouch locationInView:self];

for(int i=0;i<[arrBezierPaths count];i++)
{
    NSDictionary *dictTemp=[arrBezierPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    UIBezierPath *temppath=[dictTemp valueForKey:@"Path"];
    if([temppath containsPoint:pointTouched])
    {

      // [tempPath removeAllPoints];
        NSLog(@"This point already contain some path");
    }
}
   [globalPath addLineToPoint:[mytouch locationInView:self]];

[self setNeedsDisplay];
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

}
-(void)changeColor:(UIColor *)color
{
   UIBezierPath *temp=[[UIBezierPath alloc]init];

  //  self.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;

    temp.lineWidth=30;
    UIColor *brushColor=color;

    NSDictionary *dict=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:temp,@"Path",brushColor,@"Color", nil];
    [temp release];
    [arrBezierPaths addObject:dict];
    brushPattern=[color retain];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Need some more details. From my assumption you are drawing a line with desired color, But the next time you just wanted to replace the touch point with another color and not the whole line is it?